# Sort Pandas Dataframe by Date, Return unique Dates and then Epoch time for the top two

Tags: python, sorting, date, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
        Date Symbol
0 2015-02-20      A
1 2016-01-15      A
2 2016-01-15      A
3 2015-08-21      A
```

I need the output to be a list of the unique dates in epoch time, sorted. Like the following:
`[1424390400, 1440115200, 1452816000]`

But when I return the unique dates from the Dataframe I get:
`['2015-02-19T18:00:00.000000000-0600' '2016-01-14T18:00:00.000000000-0600'
 '2015-08-20T19:00:00.000000000-0500']`

Which shows hours that are not correct; they end up being a whole day off.

How do I sort by date, return unique, and then convert to epoch with the hour of 00:00:00? Thanks in advance.

Here's a demo script of what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame( {'Symbol':['A','A','A','A'] ,'Date'
    ['02/20/2015','01/15/2016', '01/15/2016','08/21/2015']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
dates = df['Date'].unique()
print dates
```

Comment: This was a weird one. It feels like a bug to me, but maybe someone who knows what's going on under the hood better will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, it appears that the hours are getting changed when you call `df['Date'].unique()`. The Pandas `unique()` method returns a Numpy ndarray. So this actually casts your column elements from pandas Timestamps to Numpy datetime64 types. This process is applying the weird timezones and shifts in hours.

To get a list of unique epoch time integers, try:

`dates = df['Date'].map(lambda t: t.value / (10**9)).unique()`

Since the elements of `df['Date']` are timestamps, we can get the nanosecond value by calling `t.value` and then divide by 10^9 to convert to epoch seconds.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, rather a display 'issue' with numpy. Numpy chooses to display the datetimes in local time zone (for historical reasons I think).

```
In [21]: df['Date'].unique()
Out[21]: 
array(['2015-02-19T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
       '2016-01-14T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
       '2015-08-20T20:00:00.000000000-0400'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Convert back to a DatetimeIndex (pandas returns unique as a numpy-array for compat reasons).

```
In [22]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'].unique())
Out[22]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2015-02-20, ..., 2015-08-21]
Length: 3, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

A little math gets you epoch seconds. The underling data is stored in `ns` precision.

```
In [23]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'].unique()).asi8/10**9
Out[23]: array([1424390400, 1452816000, 1440115200])
```

Note that this is all vectorized so will be quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the only hack I could come up with.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df =pd.DataFrame( {'Symbol':['A','A','A','A'] ,'Date':['02/20/2015','01/15/2016', '01/15/2016','08/21/2015']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.sort('Date')
dates = []
seen = []
for i in df['Date']:
    if i in seen:
        continue
    else:
        seen.append(i)
        dates.append(str(i).split(' ')[0])
    if len(dates)==2: 
        break
print dates
```

And then its converted to epoch using:

```
for i in dates:
    cur_dates = i.split('-')
    epoch = int((datetime(int(cur_dates[0]),int(cur_dates[1]),int(cur_dates[2]),0,0) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
    epoch = str(epoch)
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be this hard! Check out my one-liner.